# my samsung galaxy tab GT-P1000 is not charging

Tags: charging

my samsung galaxy tab GT-P1000 is not charging after i plugged in the usb cable in my laptop. but when my tablet is off it is charging but it takes so long to chrge my tablet. what will i do?

Comment: Get a legit charger? PC USB doesn't output enough current.

Comment: Even when it's on, it still changes, but slowly even though there is red cross sign on the battery icon.

Answer (score -1):

try screw the 2 dot behind the USB cable then release the cover housing using Safe Open Pry Tool then remove your battery that's it

Comment: How will removing the battery help?